# AUGraph setup on iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio

I am designing an AUGraph for an iOS application and would appreciate help on the following things.

If I want to play a number of audio files at once, does each file need an audio unit?

From the Core-Audio docs

> Linear PCM and IMA/ADPCM (IMA4) audio You can play multiple linear PCM or IMA4 format sounds simultaneously in iOS without incurring CPU resource problems.
>
> AAC, MP3, and Apple Lossless (ALAC) audio Playback for AAC, MP3, and Apple Lossless (ALAC) sounds uses efficient hardware-based decoding on iPhone and iPod touch. You can play only one such sound at a time.

So multiple AAC or MP3 files cannot be played at the same time. What is the optimal LPCM format to play multiple sounds at once?

Does this apply to Audio-Units too, as this in under the AudioQueue documentation.

Can an audio unit in an AUGraph be inactive? If an AUGraph looks like this

Speaker/output < recorder unit < mixer unit < number of audio file playing units

what happens if the recorder is not active, would it still pull, but just not write the buffers to a file?

Answer (score 2):

No; you need to use the mixer audio unit. Check this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/ConstructingAudioUnitApps/ConstructingAudioUnitApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH16-SW1

Mostly reading the document above, wrapping the sample code in a class and creating a pair of utility structures, I coded this 'Simple Sound Engine' from scratch:

<strike>ttp://nicolasmiari.com/blog/a-simple-sound-engine-for-ios-using-the-audio-unit-framework/
(Link to article in my blog containing the source code).</strike> Sorry, moved blog to Jekyll/Github and this article didn't make the cut.

<strike>...I was going to start a repo on github, but it's too much trouble. I am a visual guy, still pretty much git-phobic.</strike> Okay, that was a long time ago... Now I use git from the command line :-)

You can use it as-is, or extract the Audio Unit-related code and adapt it to your project.
I believe the Cocos Denshion 'Simple Audio Engine' does pretty much the same thing, but haven't checked the source code.

**Known issues**
If you have an exception breakpoint set for C++ exceptions, when debugging, the code will stop 2 or 3 times on `AUGraphInitialize()`. This is a 'non-crashing' exception, so you can click on continue and the code works OK.

To convert your wav files to the uncompressed .caf format, use this command on the Terminal:

```
%afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 mysoundFile.wav mySoundFile.caf
```

**EDIT:** So I created a GitHub repo after all:
https://github.com/nicolas-miari/Sound-Engine

Comment: So I dont need to convert the audio files? What if there are different formats. e.g. mp3, AAC, WAV etc. Can they all be played simultaneously without conversion?

Comment: You can play as many files as you want, as long as they are in the (uncompressed) caf format. You can play at most 1 mp3 at a time (because of the hardware)

Comment: I'll post the source code of my audio engine (I'm on an iPhone right now)

Comment: wow. I would really appreciate it. :) I will start reading that document so long. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have a look at the post soon. I do however want to do in app conversion, but I can do this no problem. I am just unsure on the file types now. The docs say that LPCM files can be played simultaneously. Do I need to convert WAV to caf then? I thought it would work correctly, but mp3 or AAC must be converted to LPCM. What would happen if I want to play 2 tracks from the ipod library using the URL? Do these need to be converted and stored somewhere first?

Comment: I don't know about the latest devices (e.g. iPhone 4S, New iPad), but last time I checked, the hardware can decode at most ONE compressed audio stream at a time (there is only one hardware decoding unit). Perhaps you can do more than one, the second one with software decoding, but I haven't researched that yet. I know you should use .caf instead of WAV as the uncompressed format. There is a doc somewhere specifying which audio formats are valid, search the Apple Developer site.

Comment: Yeah, only one compressed file can be decoded in hardware at once. I am going to use uncompressed to play multiple. I will convert to caf then. I was also wondering, if core audio uses a pull architecture, how does it work when a gesture is processed and I want to play a sound which is in an audio unit? Does the hardware pull from the mixer and the mixed pull from the audio units continuously and if there are no buffers in the audio units reading files, then it just goes on until there is or it is stopped? Doesnt this eat CPU?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13664/discussion-between-ranreloaded-and-helium3)

Answer (score 1):

Both ordinary common .wav and .caf files contain raw PCM audio samples, and can be played without hardware assist or DSP processing if already at the destination sample rate.

When there's no audio file or other synthesized data to feed an audio unit that's pulling buffers, the usual practice is to feed it buffers of silence (or perhaps a taper to zero if the previous buffer ended with non-zero amplitude).

Comment: I would like to play a sample when a button is pressed without looping the sample. In my render callback, how do I pass silence to the AudioBufferList?

Comment: May depend on your audio sample format, but usually decomposing the list into memory pointers and sizes, and copying or filling memory with that amount of zeros of the appropriate data type works, such as for linear 16-bit signed PCM.